# React: How to set width and height of an element in react component programatically

Tags: css, reactjs

I want to set a container's width and height programmatically based on some calculation.

I am trying to set style of the ref i created for the element in componentDidUpdate() but it has no effect

```
export default class CanvasOverlay extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        imageURI : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    };

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.width = 0;
        this.height = 0;
        this.canvasOverlay = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        let image = new Image();
        let that = this;
        image.onload = function() {
            that._updateDimension(image.width, image.height);
        };
        image.src = this.props.imageURI;
    }

    _updateDimension(imageWidth, imageHeight) {
        const canvasOverlay = this.canvasOverlay.current;
        //Ideally there should be some calculations to get width and 
         height
        canvasOverlay.style.width = 480;
        canvasOverlay.style.height = 400;
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div ref={this.canvasOverlay}>
                <Canvas imageURI={this.props.imageURI}/>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

HTML element canvasOverlay should have resized but it has not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems I see with the code.

- **_updateDimension** is invoked from **componentDidMount**. ComponentDidMount gets called only once in lifecycle of component, which means it will always take initial size to compute width and height. Resize of the browser will not reflect correct width and you might see overflow.
- **canvasOverlay.style.width** & **canvasOverlay.style.height** will require string instead of number. for e.g. **"400px"**

Here is a good explanation about the lifecycle of React Component: https://medium.com/@nancydo7/understanding-react-16-4-component-lifecycle-methods-e376710e5157

**Here is a working POC with the given code:** 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hosymf?file=CanvasOverlay.js

Answer (score 7):

The `style.width` and `style.height` of element doesn't accept a value with a type number so you should  convert it to a string and add a `'px'` unit.

```
element.style.width = `${width}px`;

// or

element.style.width = width + 'px';
```